# Why is (_=1)=>$=>_++ a counter

Tags: javascript

A friend got this question at a Javascript job interview:

Explain how this counter works (In other word, what is the non minimified version)

```js
    let Counter = (_=1)=>$=>_++
    let c1 = Counter()
    console.log(c1()) //1
    console.log(c1()) //2
```

Comment: Google (fat) arrow functions

Comment: [*MDN: Arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) might be helpful.

Comment: @RobG and j08691: While the arrow function references should help, a reader also has to know about default parameters and the fact that `$` and `_` are valid identifiers, and also has to understand something about closures and postfix increment operators to create a mental model of this sequence of mostly punctuation characters.  The answers help flesh this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as

```
const Counter = function(counter = 1) {
  return function count() {
    return counter++;
  };
}
```

So basically when you call `Counter()` it incapsulates `counter` with `1` as default value and every time you are calling count function returned by it, it returns counter value and increases it by 1

Answer (score 1):

```
(_=1)=>$=>_++
```

This is function that uses arrow syntax, it's equal to

```
function f(_ = 1) {
    return $ => _++;
}
```

`$ => _++;` is also arrow function, it captures closure `_` , incerements it and returns (postfix increment, so in fact it returns value and later increments it):

```
function f(_ = 1) {
    return function($) { return _++; };
}
```

So the code is equal to

```
function Counter(count = 1) {
    return function() { return count++; };
}
```

(renamed `_` to `count` and removed redundant `$` variable)

Function `Counter` will return previous value + 1 each time, starting from `count` value, like counter does

Comment: A nice breakdown!  Of course, I personally, prefer to write this function as `(_=0)=>$=>++_`  :-)